# How to get Newtonsoft.Json to serialize a property name the way I want

Tags: .net, json.net, .net-5

I'm trying to end up with JSON like this:

```
{"KIBANA_INDEX":"whatever"}
```

but when I try to use the `JsonPropertyAttribute` like this:

```
[JsonProperty(PropertyName ="KIBANA_INDEX")]
public string KibanaIndex{ get; set; }
```

I end up with JSON like this instead:

```
{"kibanA_INDEX":"whatever"}
```

Is there any way to bend Newtonsoft.Json to my will?

Comment: @Qpirate will that work though? it's the property name that is the problem, not the property value, Wouldn't I have to manually roll the entire (quite big) object in which the KIBANA_INDEX property is in.... in that case there's no point in using json.net at all...

Comment: I still have some confutions. I tried the same code and I'm able to get {"KIBANA_INDEX":"whatever"} as serialised response. I'm not sure I understand the exact issue. Are you trying to serialize a big model to get JSON like this?

Comment: I have had a further look into it, and get the same response as @Sangeethnandakumar but i am using a simple class, could we get your full model? Also do you have custom serialiser settings? there may be a contract resolver doing this strange behavour

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default, Json.Net does not behave like that.  If you provide a specific name in a `[JsonProperty]` attribute, the serializer will honor it, and you should see that in your output.  Here's an example program to demonstrate:

```
using System;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var foo = new Foo { KibanaIndex = "whatever" };
        var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(foo);
        Console.WriteLine(json);
    }
}

public class Foo
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "KIBANA_INDEX")]
    public string KibanaIndex { get; set; } 
}
```

Output:

```
{"KIBANA_INDEX":"whatever"}
```

Fiddle here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/N753GP

I suspect that you are actually using a [`CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Serialization_CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver.htm).  This resolver will cause all property names to be output as camel case, including those for which you have specified a name via a `[JsonProperty]` attribute.  Here's the same example again, except changed to use a `CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver`:

```
using System;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var foo = new Foo { KibanaIndex = "whatever" };
        var resolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
        var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings { ContractResolver = resolver };
        var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(foo, settings);
        Console.WriteLine(json);
    }
}
```

Here's the output, which should look familiar:

```
{"kibanA_INDEX":"whatever"}
```

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/KBhreA

If this is not the behavior you want, it is easy to change.  To do that, you just need to set the [`OverrideSpecifiedNames`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_Serialization_NamingStrategy_OverrideSpecifiedNames.htm) property on the `NamingStrategy` within the resolver to `false`, as shown below.  (Note that I added another property to the `Foo` class in this example to show that the camel casing is still working for properties that do *not* have a `[JsonProperty]` attribute.)

```
using System;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var foo = new Foo { KibanaIndex = "whatever", AnotherProperty = "whatever" };
        var resolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
        resolver.NamingStrategy.OverrideSpecifiedNames = false;
        var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings { ContractResolver = resolver };
        var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(foo, settings);
        Console.WriteLine(json);
    }
}

public class Foo
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "KIBANA_INDEX")]
    public string KibanaIndex { get; set; } 
    
    public string AnotherProperty { get; set; }
}
```

Output:

```
{"KIBANA_INDEX":"whatever","anotherProperty":"whatever"}
```

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/0qeP3o

Comment: You are completely right! Unbeknownst to me we HAD setup CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver without turning off OverrideSpecifiedNames. THANK YOU!

Comment: No problem; glad I could help!